# minimum spanning arborescence jgraphx

Tags: java, jgraphx

Is there any method in JGraphX which returns Minimum Spanning Arborescence for directed graphs?

I've been using getMinimumSpanningTree method, setting 'true' for 'directed' parameter, but it's actually Prim's algorithm, which fails on some directed graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know JGraphX has rather limited set of functionality. You could solve this using Mathematica and function called [FindSpanningTree](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSpanningTree.html). By default it picks most appropriate function for you, but if you want you can set **method** used to **MinimumCostArborescence**.

To find minimum spanning tree you have 3 options :

- [Prim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)
- [Kruskal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KruskalsAlgorithm.html)
- [Minimum Spanning Arborescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds'_algorithm)

Personally I would prefer Kruskal algorithm for most graphs.

In case you think setting up [JLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html) to use Mathematica is a bit overkill or want a free solution, then viable free open source alternative would be Python library [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/). Sage has method called [edge_disjoint_spanning_trees](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.edge_disjoint_spanning_trees) under generic graphs.

If you prefer this option then here are 5 ways to call python from java : [link](http://baojie.org/blog/2014/06/16/call-java-from-python/).

Comment: well, I think that using Mathematica or Python would be too complex, for I am a very beginner...   anyway, thanks for the answer :)